# Making a counter bot with Discord.py rewrite- local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I am attempting to make a counter in a discord bot that takes a number from the user and adds it to the current total. However I get  either a  " local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment" error or a "name counter is not defined" error.

I have tried 2 variations while attempting to solve my problem.

Variantion 1:

```
global counter
@bot.command()
async def bid(ctx,number):
    counter += number
    print(str(counter))
```

Variation 2:

```
@bot.command()
async def bid(ctx,number):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(str(counter))
```

Variation 1 was taken from a similar question post on StackOverflow. This is the code that returns a " local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment" error

Variation 2 was also taken from a similar question (the same question actually just a different response). This is the code that returns "name counter is not defined" error.

Expected result:

I wish to create a command that lets the users increase the count. So lets say the count is currently at 0. I want to be able to say !bid 40 and have the count go to 40. If another user says !bid 20 I want the count to go to 60.

What exactly is the problem in the code provided? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In variation 2 you have to define counter:

```
counter = 0

@bot.command()
async def bid(ctx,number):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(str(counter))
```